# solve a linear congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am studying for an exam and came upon the problem of solving the linear congruence $10 x = 15 \pmod{45}$.  I am stuck as the $10$ and $45$ are not coprime but have the $5$ as a common factor.

Comment: $ak = bk \pmod n \implies a\equiv b \pmod {\frac n{\gcd(k,n)}}$.  So $10x \equiv 15\pmod {45}\implies 2x \equiv 3\pmod 9$ and not $2$ *is* coprime to $9$ and we can continue.  And when in doubt.  Just convert to arithmetic.  $10x = 15 +45k$ so $x = \frac {15 + 45k}{10} = \frac {3 +9k}{2}$ so $k=2m+1$ is odd so $x = \frac {3 +9(2m+1)}2 = \frac {12+18m}2 = 6+9m$ so $x \equiv 6 \pmod 9$

Answer (score 1):

**Clue:**

$$45|10x-15\iff 9|2x-3$$

Comment: Following your hint, am I right in saying that x = 6 (mod 9). Thanks

Comment: Yes, @JoannSammut, you are right!

Comment: Thanks once again for your help. Much appreciated

Comment: and, @JoannSammut, you can easily check that $10(9k+6)=90k+60\equiv15\bmod45$

Comment: A useful theorem to tuck under your belt:   $ak \equiv bk \pmod n \implies a\equiv b \pmod {\frac n{\gcd(k,n)}}$.  the hint J.W.Tanner gave you should be a hint as to how to prove the theorem.